# Python - How to continue last student number count?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, error-handling

I have this menu-driven python program that lets the user create, add, and view a student record. The program stores the information in an array.

```py
MENU = """\n ---------------- MENU ---------------- \n
      Enter  [1] to Create
             [2] to View """
def main(): 
    while True:
        print(MENU)
        command = acceptCommand()
        runCommand(command)
def acceptCommand():
    while True:
        command = input("\n Enter choice: ")
        if not command in COMMANDS:
            print("\n ERROR! Command is not recognized.")
        else:
            return command
            break
def runCommand(command):
    if command == '1':
        sleep(1)
        clear()
        create()
    elif command == '2':
        sleep(1)
        clear()
        view()
studentRecord = [] 

def create():
    print("\n \t ------- CREATE STUDENT INFORMATION ------- \n")

    recordSize = int (input("\n Enter Number of Students: "))

    for size in range(recordSize):
        studentNumber = size + 1
        print("\n -------------------------------------------------")
        print("\n Student No.", studentNumber)
        studentName = input(" Student Name: ")
        math = int(input("\n \t \t Math Grade: "))
        science = int(input("\t \t Science Grade: "))
        english = int(input("\t \t English Grade: "))
        filipino = int(input("\t \t Filipino Grade: "))
        average = float((math + science + english + filipino)/4)
        average = round(average, 2)
        print("\n \t \t Average Grade is:", average)
        studentRecord.append([studentNumber, studentName, math, science, english, filipino, average])

    print("\n----------------------------------")
    print("Student Data created successfully!")
    print("----------------------------------")
    input("\n \t Press any key to continue...")
    clear() # This basically clears the screen and goes to the menu

def view():
    print("\n \t ------- VIEW STUDENT RECORD -------")
    print("\n -------------------------------------------------")
    for student in studentRecord:
        print(f" Student No. {student[0]}")
        print(f" Student Name: {student[1]}")
        print(f"\n \t Math Grade: {student[2]}")
        print(f"\t Science Grade: {student[3]}")
        print(f"\t English Grade: {student[4]}")
        print(f"\t Filipino Grade: {student[5]}")
        print(f"\n \t Average: {student[6]}")
        print(" -------------------------------------------------")   
    input("\n Press enter to continue...")
    clear() # This basically clears the screen and goes to the menu
```

So in this program you can create and view the student record you made, and then you can go back to the `create()` function again to add another set of record.

My problem here is that whenever I try to make another set of records, the student number goes back to '1' again.

For example, I added 1 student to my record. But instead of displaying `Student No. 3`. It displays `Student No. 1` again

```
         ------- VIEW STUDENT RECORD -------

 -------------------------------------------------        
 Student No. 1
 Student Name: Harry

         Math Grade: 99
         Science Grade: 99
         English Grade: 99
         Filipino Grade: 99

         Average: 99.0
 -------------------------------------------------        
 Student No. 2
 Student Name: Luke

         Math Grade: 89
         Science Grade: 89
         English Grade: 89
         Filipino Grade: 89

         Average: 89.0
 -------------------------------------------------  
# This is my new added data
  
 Student No. 1
 Student Name: Michael

         Math Grade: 78
         Science Grade: 77
         English Grade: 77
         Filipino Grade: 77

         Average: 77.25
 -------------------------------------------------        

 Press enter to continue...
```

I tried removing the `studentNumber = size + 1` part because I think that's the root of my error.

I tried replacing it by `studentNumber = [x+1 for x in studentRecord[0]]` but it prompts out an error message, "*IndexError: list index out of range*"

Is there any possible way of continuing the count of the last student no.?

Comment: `studentNumber = [x+1 for x in studentRecord[0]]` is erroring out because the first time through, studentRecord has no elements.  And later you will have a problem because you are creating a list

Answer (score 1):

```py
def create():
    print("\n \t ------- CREATE STUDENT INFORMATION ------- \n")

    recordSize = int (input("\n Enter Number of Students: "))

    studentNumber = len(studentRecord)

    for size in range(recordSize):
        studentNumber = studentNumber + size
        print("\n -------------------------------------------------")
        print("\n Student No.", studentNumber)
        studentName = input(" Student Name: ")
```

I think studentNumber is initially defined on this line `recordSize = int (input("\n Enter Number of Students: "))`

If you want know the last studentNumber,
you have to get length of studentRecord

Does this work for you?

Comment: That is it exactly.  Every time you call create the new student number will be offset by the existing number of students.